# Jest: putting variable directly in describe-block vs. beforeAll

Tags: testing, jestjs

I know that having shared state between tests is bad practice and should be avoided if possible. But I'm just curious how are these two constructs below different in Jest:

**describe-block**

```js
describe('test suite', () => {
  const theAnswer = 42;

  test('a test case', () => {
    expect(theAnswer + 1).toEqual(43);
  });

  test('another test case', () => {
    expect(theAnswer + -1).toEqual(41);
  });
});
```

vs.

**beforeAll**

```js
describe('test suite with beforeAll', () => {
  let theAnswer;
  beforeAll(() => {
    theAnswer = 42;
  });

  test('a test case', () => {
    expect(theAnswer + 1).toEqual(43);
  });

  test('another test case', () => {
    expect(theAnswer + -1).toEqual(41);
  });
});
```

What's the significance of using `beforeAll` if we can directly declare a shared variable/state in the `describe` block?

Comment: What is your state in the example?

Comment: The variable called `theAnswer`?

Comment: It looks like a constant, its value will not be changed in the test :-?.

Comment: A state doesn't have to be mutable, does it? :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the doc [One-Time Setup](https://jestjs.io/docs/setup-teardown#one-time-setup):

> This can be especially bothersome when the setup is asynchronous, so you can't do it inline. Jest provides `beforeAll` and `afterAll` to handle this situation.

If the setup is synchronous like yours, declaring the variables in the `describe` block is OK.

> If setup was synchronous, you could do this without `beforeAll`. The key is that Jest will wait for a promise to resolve, so you can have asynchronous setup as well.

But if the setup is asynchronous, you can't do it inside `describe` block. You must do it in `before*` and `after*` hooks.

E.g.

```js
describe('test suite', () => {
  let theAnswer;
  beforeAll((done) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      theAnswer = 42;
      done();
    }, 1_000);
  });

  test('a test case', () => {
    expect(theAnswer + 1).toEqual(43);
  });

  test('another test case', () => {
    expect(theAnswer + -1).toEqual(41);
  });
});
```

Jest will wait for the setup to be done before running the test cases.

See the doc about [beforeAll](https://jestjs.io/docs/26.x/api#beforeallfn-timeout)